# Wordpress: Uncaught ReferenceError: Velocity is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, velocity

I have implemented some javascript (materializecss) on my site but I keep getting the following error messages: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Velocity is not defined`

I understand, this error is due to missing jQuery, but I should mention, that my site is using Wordpress, which already have jQuery library, right?

Comment: The only errors you're likely to see from a missing jQuery are  `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` and `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. jQuery does not define a `Velocity` variable.

Comment: Alright, but why is there conflict with jQuery then?
If I add jquery manualy into footer, script will work.

ad. excuse me, since I'm learning this stuff. Maybe I'm asking wrong. :/

Comment: Could it be a version conflict between your jQueries? Or your WP is using an old version?

Comment: @EinarSundgren wooo, you are right. WP is using older jQuery- 1.11.1.

Thank you! And I'm truly sorry, for dumb question.

Comment: Ill just convert that to an answer then.

Comment: Of course, I will mark as solved. (=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely caused by your WP installation using an older version of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

If you use 0.97 (i'm not exactly sure)

```
// Velocity has conflicts when loaded with jQuery, this will check for it
var Vel;
if ($) {
  Vel = $.Velocity;
}
else {
  Vel = Velocity; // change value with jQuery.Velocity
}
```